# How to select what bundles a certain html page will use?

Tags: webpack, pug-loader

**the project**

I have a project where the website view is written using Pug, then compiled to HTML.

> index.pug ---> index.html

Because I want the project to have more than one page, I have got this, as well:

> about.pug ---> about.html

Now, each of these pages have entries, in `webpack.config.js`:

```js
{
  entry: {
    index: ['scripts/index.ts'],
    about: ['scripts/about.ts'],
  }
}
```

I don't think it's good to have a single bundle for both, because there's imported modules which are unique to each page entry (that is: if I know what I'm talking about).

**the problem**

When the HTML is generated, [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) automatically injects **both bundles** in **both pages**, which is worse then what I just explained.

How can I tell it to inject just the bundle I want?

*ps: I tried including each of them, manually in the `*.pug` files. Although, generated bundle filenames have hashes, in order to achieve cache busting.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before writing this question, I spent three hours searching for a solution.

Although, right after submitting it, I refreshed search page and found the solution.

It's about chunks.

You pass a hash of options to `html-webpack-plugin`, in which there's a property named "chunks". This property can take an array of string, with the names of desired entries.

```js
{
  plugins: [

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'views/index.pug',
      scriptLoading: 'defer',
      filename: 'index.html',
      chunks: [
        "index"
      ]
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'views/about.pug',
      scriptLoading: 'defer',
      filename: 'about.html',
      chunks: [
        "about"
      ]
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPugPlugin()
  ]
}
```

Sorry for the trouble.